# Retrofit parse a json with dynamic keys

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to use retrofit for my webservices.
I am getting a problem how can I define an object with dynamic Keys.
I am trying to get data for today and tomorrow. Dates will always change.

Here is the json:

```
{ "2015-11-13": [  ], "2015-11-14": [  ]}
```

Comment: Can you tell us the pattern to decide date?

Comment: the webservice always return a jsonarray for today and a jsonarray for tomorrow

Comment: What parser are you using with retrofit? GSON?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GSON I guess you can declare the response as JsonObject in your call like this :

```
@GET("your_api_path")
Call<JsonObject> getDateData();
```

And then parse it when you get the response

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<YourModel>> >() {}.getType();
Map<String, List<YourModel>> result= gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, mapType);
```

Comment: Could u please help for following parsing, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33758601/2624806)