# Parse Dynamic Key Json String using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm trying to parse following dynamic key Json String.

```
"report":{
    "data":{
        "results":{
            "558952cca6d73d7d81c2eb9d":{
                "Max":-1,
                "Min":-1,
                "Slope":-1,
            },

            "558ce148a6d73d7d81c2fa8a":{
                "Max":-2,
                "Min":-1,
                "Slope":-2,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following I'm trying to get data, but getting error while parse last dynamic json String.

```
 public class Report {
        @SerializedName("data")
        @Expose
        private Data data;

        public Data getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(Data data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Report{" +
                    "data=" + data +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public class Data {
        @SerializedName("results")
        @Expose
        private ResultInside result;

        public ResultInside getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        public void setResult(ResultInside result) {
            this.result = result;
        }
    }

    public class ResultInside {
        /*@SerializedName("results")
        @Expose*/
        private Map<String, Vitals> elemDetails = new HashMap<>();

        public Map<String, Vitals> getElemDetails() {
            return elemDetails;
        }

        public void setElemDetails(Map<String, Vitals> elemDetails) {
            this.elemDetails = elemDetails;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion how to parse in this case !

Comment: @Shubh Hai, I am having the same issue, I don't know how to add Pojo class for Dynamic Key, Can you tell what you have used in Vitals Class?

Comment: @MathaN check with json string and respected Data class. Report -> Data -> results -> Vitals. And so vital contain max, min, slope as variable. 

I did mistake to Create another ResulInside class inside Result with thought, it will map **runtime Key** with **Vitals** class but that is not the case. Check accepted answer below, instead to create **ResultInsid** handle it **Result** class itself.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your `resultInside` class is adding an extra object layer that does not exist in your JSON.  Try moving the map to your `Data` class `results` field.

```
public class Data {
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, Vitals> result;

    //....
}
```

Comment: In retrofit if you want to parse JSON with dynamic keys (with dynamic names) you need to use HashMap for sure. So this answer is the correct one +1 from me. Just make sure you are putting you HashMap on object level which has static name (not dynamic name)

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my times :)

Comment: How to handle(receive data from) the situation if one of children of each dynamic key is JSONArray of JSONObjects. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why this works? It looks like GSON is skipping the dynamically named key but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 12):

A better way to do this, would be:

```
----------------------

public class Report {
        @SerializedName("data")
        @Expose
        private Data data;

----------------------

public class Data {


    public HashMap<String, DataValues> dataValues;


    public Data() {
        this.dataVaues = new HashMap<>();
    }
}

-----------------------------
```

then, create a Parser class like this:

```
public class DataParser implements JsonDeserializer<Data> {


    @Override
    public Data deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        Data result = new Data();


        try {
            final HashMap<String, DataValues> map = readServiceUrlMap(json.getAsJsonObject());

            if(map != null) {
                result.dataValues = map;
            }

        }catch (JsonSyntaxException ex){
            return null;
        }

        return result;
    }


    private HashMap<String, DataValues> readServiceUrlMap(final JsonObject jsonObject) throws JsonSyntaxException {

        if(jsonObject == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        HashMap<String, DataValues> products = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {

            String key = entry.getKey();
            DataValues value = gson.fromJson(entry.getValue(), DataValues.class);
            products.put(key, value);
        }
        return products;
    }


----------------------------------------------
```

after that, type this in your ApiClient class

```
public class ApiClient {


    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {

        if(retrofit == null) {

            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Data.class, new DataParser());

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonBuilder.create()))
                    .build();
```

I hope this will help someone

Comment: Ruben Caster, what is DataValues class here ?

Comment: your own model with use case info (the class inside DATA -> public HashMap<String, DataValues> dataValues;