# How to convert a Map to Arraylist of Objects?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Suppose I have having Json response like this:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "29": "Hardik sheth",
    "30": "Kavit Gosvami"
  }
}
```

I am using Retrofit to parse Json response. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758601/parse-dynamic-key-json-string-using-retrofit) answer I will have to use `Map<String, String>` which will give all the data in Map. Now what I want is `ArrayList<PojoObject>`.

**PojoObject.class**

```
public class PojoObject {
    private String mapKey, mapValue;

    public String getMapKey() {
        return mapKey;
    }

    public void setMapKey(String mapKey) {
        this.mapKey = mapKey;
    }

    public String getMapValue() {
        return mapValue;
    }

    public void setMapValue(String mapValue) {
        this.mapValue = mapValue;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to convert a `Map<key,value>` to a `List<PojoObject>`?

Comment: Are you having dyanamic keys too?

Comment: @VivekMishra yes

Comment: why do you need a list in the first place? a map is the better container for the data.. anyway if you really need it just to a simple loop through the map and create your `PojoObject` objects for the list, what exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you can expand your class to have a constructor taking the values as well:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .map(e -> new PojoObject(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you can't:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .map(e -> {
       PojoObject po = new PojoObject();
       po.setMapKey(e.getKey());
       po.setMapValue(e.getValue());
       return po;
 }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that this uses Java 8 `Stream` API.

Comment: Can we use this stream as reusable like generic function

Comment: @jebinhector What exactly are you referring to? The result is a List, and if you mean the temporary Stream then no, you cannot reuse Streams.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Java has exact POJO [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) like you want. Hence, you can extract the entry set from map and iterate over the entry set like below or you can further convert the set to list like in next snippet and continue with your processing.

```
 //fetch entry set from map
Set<Entry<String, String>> set = map.entrySet();        

    for(Entry<String, String> entry: set) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() +"," + entry.getValue());
    }

    //convert set to list
    List<Entry<String, String>> list = new ArrayList(set);

    for(Entry<String, String> entry: list) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() +"," + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: Note that it is not possible to change the key's value with `Map.Entry`, which makes OP's dynamic keys impossible.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>(map.values());
```

Or

```
hashMap.keySet().toArray(); // returns an array of keys
hashMap.values().toArray(); // returns an array of values
```

**Should be noted that the ordering of both arrays may not be the same.**

or

```
hashMap.entrySet().toArray();
```

Comment: This works if it is a `Map<Key, PojoObject>`. If it is a `Map<String, String>` though, as stated by OP, it will create an `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: this is wrong. map.values() will return an List<String> of just the values: "Hardik sheth","Kavit Gosvami"

Comment: The edit did not solve the problem, you still don't have `PojoObject`s.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this method to convert map to list

```
List<PojoObject> list = new ArrayList<PojoObject>(map.values());
```

Assuming:

```
Map <Key,Value> map;
```

Comment: This works if it is a `Map<Key, PojoObject>`. If it is a `Map<String, String>` though, as stated by OP, it will create an `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: This will not work as It Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayList(java.util.Collection<java.lang.String>;

Answer (score -3):

```
ArrayList<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
```

this may be the best way.