# how do i create POJO class for json with dynamic keys for retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "warnings": {
    "main": {
      "*": "Unrecognized parameter: rvprop."
    },
    "extracts": {
      "*": "\"exlimit\" was too large for a whole article extracts request, lowered to 1."
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "normalized": [
      {
        "from": "pune",
        "to": "Pune"
      }
    ],
    "pages": {
      "164634": {
        "pageid": 164634,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Pune",
        "extract": ""
                }
            }
      }
}
```

---

In the above json the numeric key inside "pages" object is dynamic. So how do i make a pojo for this json.

Please, please, please help me.
I've searched a lot for this, but go nothing that works.
Also i'm a beginner in retrofit, so please answer in detail.
I've seen some answers which mention use of map for such cases (eg. [Parse Dynamic Key Json String using Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758601/parse-dynamic-key-json-string-using-retrofit)). But those answers are not elaborated properly. please help me understand it thoroughly.

Comment: Don't just Ask Question Directly.You have to try yourself ,And if you are not able to solve issue ,then ask with Demonstration.
Look at this this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527264/how-to-create-a-pojo

Comment: seon, I know how to make pojo classes which is explained in that link. But the problem is with json having  dynamic keys. Please help me if you know.

Comment: @SahilPatil Did you try with hashmap solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can use A `hashmap` for additional properties/ dynamic properties in your `Pages` class

```
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Query {
    private List<Address> normalized ;
    private Map<String, Pages> pages;
    //getter & Setter
    public Map<String, Pages>  getPages() {
        return pages;
    }
    public void setPages(Map<String, Pages>  pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public class Pages {
        private String pageid;
        private int ns;
        private String title;
        private String extract;
        //define all getter and setter methods
    }

    public class Address{
    private String from;
    private String to;
    }
}
```

> //add data in Pages class by using setter methods. Page pageObj = new Page(); pageObj.setPageid("164634"); pageObj.setns(0); ...
>   Create local Map Map pagesObj = new HashMap<>();
>   pagesObj.put("164634", pageObj);
>   use setPages(pagesObj); to set value