# a set of unknown keys, how to parse this json object in retrofit, i want this data into any arraylist after parsing, can anyone suggest a n solution

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I tried this solution : [Parse Dynamic Key Json String using Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758601/parse-dynamic-key-json-string-using-retrofit/33759662#33759662)
but not got the proper solution

input data is :

```
{
    "details": {
        "10": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "sample_data1"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "sampledata_2"
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to parse this json object with the unkwon keys

Comment: _a set of unknown keys.._ But  you seem to know the structure of _input data_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this using GSON

```
JsonObject detailsJson = new JsonParser("JsonString").getAsJsonObject();
List<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> jsonMap: detailsJson.entrySet()){
    //get the json array or 
    //jsonMap.getValue().getAsJsonArray();  do something else
    //or parse it to some model
    SomeModel obj = gson.fromJson(jsonMap.getValue(),SomeModel.class);
    list.add(obj);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started

```
    JSONObject details = new JSONObject("details");
    Iterator keys = details.keys();

    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        // loop to get the dynamic key
        String dynamicKeys = (String)keys.next();

        // get the value of the dynamic key
        JSONObject dynamicValue = details.getJSONObject(dynamicKeys);

        // do something here with the value...
    }
```

Comment: how to do it with retrofit gson converter