# Parsing nested json objects in retrofit android

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm not able to parse json in retrofit, this is my sample json, the keys are dynamic, what POJO definition is needed for such json data:

```
    {
    "Fri Mar 23 2018 17:35:36 GMT+0530 (IST)": {
        "PDF": "",
        "URL": "",
        "image": "",
        "shortDescription": "test one",
        "timestamp": "2018-03-23T12:05:36.319Z",
        "title": "test "
    },
    "Fri Mar 23 2018 17:44:43 GMT+0530 (IST)": {
        "PDF": "",
        "URL": "",
        "image": "",
        "shortDescription": "two test",
        "timestamp": "2018-03-23T12:14:43.194Z",
        "title": "two"
    },
    "Fri Mar 23 2018 17:49:06 GMT+0530 (IST)": {
        "PDF": "",
        "URL": "https://twitter.com/CodingDoug/status/942576182276497409",
        "image": "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gBUaAVdAttmAqv68OChHCDqlbKAoxZW6",
        "shortDescription": "test three",
        "timestamp": "2018-03-23T12:19:06.835Z",
        "title": "three"
    },
    "Mon Mar 26 2018 15:56:06 GMT+0530 (IST)": {
        "PDF": "",
        "URL": "https://www.goodmorningquote.com/inspirational-monday-quotes-start-happy/",
        "image": "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fg1z0_jzTUUiXhvkHyGLewJC2LFFzEyW",
        "shortDescription": "1st day of week, great day to plan and jumpstart week ",
        "timestamp": "2018-03-26T10:26:06.983Z",
        "title": "Monday test 1 "
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Dynamic Key Json String using Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758601/parse-dynamic-key-json-string-using-retrofit)

Comment: check this links https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+parse+dynamic+key+json+using+retrofit+in+android+site:stackoverflow.com&client=ubuntu&hs=QGZ&channel=fs&dcr=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg3cCzwLbaAhVJso8KHVBkAvwQrQIoBDAAegQIABA4&biw=1407&bih=738

Answer (score 2):

Try `Map<String, Object>` to parse the json. String is the variable key here.
Object is the POJO for your "PDF" , "URL",
        "image",
        "shortDescription",
        "timestamp",
        "title": "test "

Answer (score 0):

you can create class like below for json parsing :

```
Gson gson = GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        List<ModelClass> dataList= new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject issueObj = new JSONObject(jsonContent);
          Iterator iterator = issueObj.keys();
           while(iterator.hasNext()){
            String key = (String)iterator.next();
            JSONObject issue = issueObj.getJSONObject(key);


        ModelClass model = gson.fromJson(issue.toString(), ModelClass.class);

    dataList.add(model);
            }
```

and your model class would be :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ModelClass implements Serializable
{

@SerializedName("PDF")
@Expose
private String pDF;
@SerializedName("URL")
@Expose
private String uRL;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;
@SerializedName("shortDescription")
@Expose
private String shortDescription;
@SerializedName("timestamp")
@Expose
private String timestamp;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;


public String getPDF() {
return pDF;
}

public void setPDF(String pDF) {
this.pDF = pDF;
}

public String getURL() {
return uRL;
}

public void setURL(String uRL) {
this.uRL = uRL;
}

public String getImage() {
return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
this.image = image;
}

public String getShortDescription() {
return shortDescription;
}

public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

}
```

Comment: dude, keys are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

when you getting json data make retrofit object and make pojo class 
if want to generate pojo class refer this site..
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

put your json data it provide all pojo class..

then make retrofit object like below ..
make Apiclient class like

```
public class ApiClient {
private final static String BASE_URL = "https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/";
public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}

private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
}
```

then make interface for api call like below

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("marvel/")
Call<List<Hero>> getHero(); // here pass your response pojo class name.
}
```

in main activity how to call like below ..

```
 ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getInstance().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

Call<List<Hero>> call = apiInterface.getHero();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Hero>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Hero>> call, Response<List<Hero>> response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Hero>> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```