# Parsing JSON data in retrofit where object value comes dynamically

Tags: android

{
    "status": "200",
    "errorMessage": "",
    "data": {
        "cleaner_tasks": {
            "2018-08-02": {
                "Mahindra & Mahindra": {
                    "tasks": {
                        "37": {
                            "customer_name": "Neelam",
                            "contact_no": "94625917" 
                        },
                        "38": {
                            "customer_name": "Neelam",
                            "contact_no": "9462591789"
                        }
                    },
                    "address": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Mahindra & Mahindra"
                }
            },
            "2018-08-03": {
                "Mahindra & Mahindra": {
                    "tasks": {
                        "42": {
                            "customer_name": "Neelam",
                            "contact_no": "946259178"
                        },
                        "43": {
                            "customer_name": "Neelam",
                            "contact_no": "9462591789"
                        }
                    },
                    "address": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Mahindra & Mahindra"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "originalRequest": {},
    "detailError": ""
}
}

> Blockquote "here most off object key value comes dynamically " then how to crete a pojo class for retrofit

Comment: Maybe you should correct question title to state that object KEY is dynamically changed, but not object value. @MichaelDodd you reference is not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @redlabrat Noted. Question was just a JSON dump at the time with no context, so that's what I interpreted the question as. It's still unclear what OP is asking though IMO.

Comment: But as reference you should look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758601/parse-dynamic-key-json-string-using-retrofit

Comment: @MichaelDodd the question is how to decode the JSON for the retrofit library. here the name of multiple objects comes dynamically. so I can't decode it. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` Formatting is not proper.
`cleaner_tasks` should be `jsonArray` not `JsonObject`

but you can't Formate response then use as Follows.

```
 try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(Data);
        JSONObject DataJsonObject = object.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONObject CleanerTaskJsonObject = DataJsonObject.getJSONObject("cleaner_tasks");

        Iterator<String> keys = CleanerTaskJsonObject.keys();
        while(keys.hasNext())
        {
          String aKey= keys.next();
            //all keys are here
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: please guide me how to use it like pojo class in retrofit

Comment: it is not feasible  to create model class for every request . use `ResponseBody` for `response` as String . its my opinion .but it's all up to yours.

Comment: ok , one more question is in this line "  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(Data) "  what is the Data

Comment: your  json string