# How can I @SerializedName this response "name.0"

Tags: java, android, gson

I have this project running in **Retrofit** with **Gson** serialized response, but now the API is respond with this kind of array `name.0` and this **0** is the index of array, thats mean if the response send 100 items I supposedly create this in code 100 times.

This the response:

```
{
    "name.0": [
        "Here is the message"
    ],
    "name.1": [
        "Here is the message"
    ],
    "name.2": [
        "Here is the message"
    ],
    ...

}
```

This is my code for `name` array:

```
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private List<String> name = null;
```

I don't want to do this:

```
@SerializedName("name.0")
@Expose
private List<String> name0 = null;

@SerializedName("name.1")
@Expose
private List<String> name1 = null;

@SerializedName("name.2")
@Expose
private List<String> name2 = null;

...
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: May be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53082050/2078074) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

While not the prettiest solution, you could make your endpoint call to return a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

This way you won't have to write all of the possible values of the "name" field and your map will have something like

```
{name.0=[Here is the message], name.1=[Here is the message], name.2=[Here is the message]}
```