# How to parse dynamic key json using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

[image]I have below response from an API 
How to parse the Json below using retrofit?

```
{
   "country1":{
            "id":"0",
            "name":"Jack"
   }, 

   "country2":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Rick"
   }

}
```

my data classes

```
data class Countries(@Expose var country: Map<String, Country>)
data class Country(var id: String, var name: String)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758601/parse-dynamic-key-json-string-using-retrofit

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I implement this solution but this not works, please see my data classes

Comment: I had done this without retrofit

Answer (score 0):

Gson is generating the JSON like this -

```
data class Json4Kotlin_Base (

    @SerializedName("country1") val country1 : Country1,
    @SerializedName("country2") val country2 : Country2
)
```

Can use Jackson for hashmap mapping