# How can I fetch dynamic data from Rest API

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit2

I'm coding an Android app. I'm using Retrofit2 for Rest API. I know how can fetch and collect data but the API returns data like this:

```
"data": {
        "A": {
            "name1": {
                "zone_id": 1,
                "name": "name1"
            },
            "name2": {
                "zone_id": 2,
                "name": "name2"
            },
            "name3": {
                "zone_id": 3,
                "name": "name3"
            }
        }
    }
```

I created that classes: data, A, name1, name2, name3 but the object's count may increase or decrease. If API return name4 I must update my code. If API returns Array I know how can code but I don't know what to do on this story.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758601/parse-dynamic-key-json-string-using-retrofit

Comment: @mayankmodi thank you, that's the solution :)

Comment: @Shashanth yes it is