# How to parse json with unknown keys in android

Tags: android, json

Hi I am using retrofit to send and receive data from server.How to parse if the keys are different.

Can any one help me how to parse json with below keys.

```
{"users": {"19x1": "Admin","19x5": "Manager"}}
```

Comment: Parse them to a dictionary

Comment: @TommySadiqHinrichsen how to can you please explain me in details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: if my response contains 500 records

Comment: No. of iterations your `JSON` contains of an object doesn't matter, what matters is that can you make an object class of it to parse using `GSON`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse Dynamic Key Json String using Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758601/parse-dynamic-key-json-string-using-retrofit)

Answer (score 1):

The keys are not the problem the user should be an object

```
{ 
  "users": {
  "19x1": "Admin",
  "19x5": "Manager"
  }
}
```

Try the above code in any json validator to check.. ie https://jsonlint.com/

Updated to access the values:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>How to access nested JSON objects.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myObj = { 
  "users": {
  "19x1": "Admin",
  "19x5": "Manager"
  }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj.users["19x1"];
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and for Android:

```
JSONObject jsonString = {"users": {"19x1": "Admin","19x5": "Manager"}};

JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject obj2=obj1.getJSONObject("users");
JSONObject obj3=obj2.getJSONObject("19x1");

System.out.println("The value is " + obj3);
```

Comment: based on your changes, that is valid json.. check it on a json validator.

Comment: how to parse this json

Comment: Do you mean how to access the values?

Comment: Not in html in android

Comment: @norcaljohnny Your implementation is slick right but the OP is trying parse dynamic json keys using `Gson` library. That is just not possible.

Comment: @AouledIssa no disrespect to the OP but the question has been re-edited about 5 times with a wee bit more info added each time..Earlier in the post it seemed as if it was an invalid json oversight, hence the other answers. But thank you for the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `json` structure is not correct. Basically you are having an array of users but you return object that has two fields `19x1` and `19x2`.

It's not possible to use `Retrofit` and `Gson` to parse a dynamic `key` response. The only way to do is to use Plain `Json` Parsing in Android. but you will need to know where is the data in the list so you can do something like.

`jsonArray.getObject(index)`

if you want to get a list of objects then change your `json` to this structure

```
"users": [
    {
        "role_id": "19x1",
        "description": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "role_id": "19x5",
        "description": "Manager"
    }
]
```

Comment: How to parse please let me know

Comment: are you looking to parse a list of users? I need to know cuz if it's the case then your json may be incorrect

Comment: list of the users

Answer (score 0):

The json you gave is not correct.It should be like this:

```
{"users": {"19x1": "Admin","19x5": "Manager"}}
```

You can check the accuracy of json object in here: https://www.bejson.com/

Comment: Not a correct!! Gson doesn't work in this fashion. You need to know the parse model to be able to parse. Otherwise you will just have to parse using plain using plain java json parsing